# Weird catch-all issue on Postfix

Tags: linux, postfix

I have set the Postfix and virtual mapping successfully:

```
virtual_mailbox_domains = test.com test2.com
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/mail/virtualhosts
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox
virtual_minimum_uid = 500
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
allow_mail_to_commands = forward
```

Then in /etc/postfix/virtual, I set the following catch-all rule:

```
test@test.com test@gmail.com
test2@test.com test2@gmail.com
@test.com test_catchall
```

In /etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox, I set these:

```
pop1@test.com test.com_pop1
pop2@test.com test.com_pop2
```

By the way, I already created a system user "test_catchall".

Now, the weird thing begins. When I send an email to bounce@test.com, it's captured by "test_catchall" account. No problem so far. But if I send an email to one of the set system user accounts, it's still being captured by test_catchall instead of the real owner.

Catch-all works properly for virtual aliases however.

What am I doing wrong?

Tahnks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If my memory serves me right, in the past I had to use **virtual_maps** instead of **virtual_alias_maps**.